# eclipse cannot find my templates dir in django project

Tags: django, eclipse, path

recently I want to learn django in eclipse, but when I set up eclipse environment , I get a problem...

### the django project cannot find my templates folder in eclipse

in the setting.py:

import os

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.abspath('templates'),
)
```

the templates folder:

```
D:\django_workspace\eagle\eagle\templates
```

I run 'manage.py shell' and get:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('templates')  
'D:\\django_workspace\\eagle\\eagle\\templates'
```

but, in eclipse I run the command:

```
>>>os.path.abspath('templates')  
'D:\\Program Files\\eclipse\\templates'
```

it seems that the os root path is set to be 'D:\Program Files\eclipse' where I install the eclispe

how can I solve this problem ??

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it, you're getting the absolute path from a relative path based on the current working directory, so, your code will fail depending on your current directory...

Better would be actually calculating the path based on `__file__` from your module (something as `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')` -- not really sure where your settings file is relative to your templates, so, in your environment it may be a bit different.

Comment: Thanks, this method is marvellous, though I used absolute address